# Hydra returning error: "module option must start with http"

Tags: passwords, brute-force, hydra

I am trying to brute force a web login password using hydra with the below command:

```
hydra -s 8123 -x 2:8:aA1 -t 16 -m http://192.168.1.193 http-proxy
```

I get

> [ERROR] module option must start with http://

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: this has nothing to do with a proxy, you are just trying to use hydra on a web login and getting an error

Comment: hydra is open source, you can find out exactly why you get the error by searching for the error in the code itself: https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/blob/d754411a96e1db5d6e592f7bd9cdff655a86d9a2/hydra.c

Comment: you need to verify what the syntax is to use the http-proxy option - you need to check your documentation